# Redis publish encoded data

Tags: redis, publish-subscribe, node-redis

I have data encoded as:

```
"{\"brand\":\"newBrand\",\"Id\":\"1\",\"field\":\"1\",\"date\":1437487498449,\"period\":2,\"newUser\":0}"
```

Can I publish these data as is with PUBLISH command or I have to parse into some other format and then PUBLISH new formatted data?

I want to publish these data and show them on the frontend (table).

Comment: Yes - Redis is oblivious to the content of messages sent via PubSub. Instead of asking here, simply set up a little test.

Comment: @user3265921 Does my answer help ? If yes then please accept it otherwise ask away if anything is unclear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. PUBLISH sends data as is and then the rest depends on how you use it.